# Access impossible to newly setup EJBCA PKI

Tags: networking, port, wildfly, pki, ejbca

I have just finished installing ejbca community edition on top of wildfly.
The EJBCA server is a VM in the azure cloud.

everything went fine during build : Build successful for every 3 steps of deployment.

```
- ant deployear
- ant runinstall
- ant deploy-keystore)
```

Versions :

```
Wildfly 18.0
EJBCA 7.4.3.2 
Ant 1.10.10
Mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.27-MariaDB
JDBC connector : mariadb 2.7.3 
Debian 10 buster
```

However i am unable to reach the destination

```
https://<public ip address>:8443/ejbca/
```

Error message :

```
    The connection has timed out
    
    The server at <my public ip @> is taking too long to respond.
```

So, started checking the different ports open :

```
    **remote** nmap scan from my local vm to the remote EJBCA VM : 

    nmap -Pn8080,22,8442,8443,9990,3306 52.188.59.103
    
    Host is up (0.037s latency).
    Not shown: 995 filtered ports
    PORT     STATE SERVICE
    21/tcp   open  ftp
    80/tcp   open  http
    443/tcp  open  https
    554/tcp  open  rtsp
    1723/tcp open  pptp
    
    Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 5.62 seconds
```

On the EJBCA VM a **local port** scan shows that port 8443 and 8080 are open :

```
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost
Not shown: 996 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
3306/tcp open  mysql
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
8443/tcp open  https-alt
```

Azure connectivity tests from my ip to EJBCA host is OK for every ports tested.

however, online Port check says ports 8443 and 8442 are closed
https://portchecker.co/

So i don't know which test to trust ?

I tried disabling both my local firewall and my proxy but it didn't make any difference.

I did a tcpdump on the EJBCA server whilst trying to access ejbca url : but nothing was displayed.

What am i missing here ?
What other tests can i perform?

EDIT :

serverlog: (errors and warnings )

web admin error:

```
 2021-06-14 13:00:07,332 ERROR [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJSF0002: Could not load JSF managed bean class: org.ejbca.ui.web.admin.peerconnector.PeerConnectorsMBean
2021-06-14 13:00:07,433 ERROR [org.jboss.as.jsf] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYJSF0002: Could not load JSF managed bean class: org.ejbca.ui.web.admin.peerconnector.PeerConnectorMBean
```

Deprecated lib:

```
2021-06-14 13:00:14,598 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000146: BeforeBeanDiscovery.addAnnotatedType(AnnotatedType<?>) used for class com.sun.faces.flow.FlowDiscoveryCDIHelper is deprecated from CDI 1.1!
```

Severe errors :

```
2021-06-14 13:00:15,967 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.flow] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
2021-06-14 13:00:15,971 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application.view] (MSC service thread 1-4) Unable to obtain CDI 1.1 utilities for Mojarra
```

Warnings:

```
2021-06-14 13:00:16,770 INFO  [org.ejbca.core.ejb.StartupSingletonBean] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 94) Init, EJBCA 7.4.3.2 Community (67479006a69140e81d66e39871bed8255362effc) startup.
2021-06-14 13:00:16,780 WARN  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 66) UT015020: Path /* is secured for some HTTP methods, however it is not secured for [HEAD, POST, GET]
2021-06-14 13:00:16,780 WARN  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) UT015020: Path /* is secured for some HTTP methods [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

During startup WildFly should log something like the following, so you can verify that WildFly is configured to listen on ports for all IPs.

```
16:58:12,890 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-7) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener httpspriv listening on 0.0.0.0:8443
16:58:12,920 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-8) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTPS listener httpspub listening on 0.0.0.0:8442
```

You can also try connecting to port 8442, to check that the problem is not that you don't have the client certificate in your browser.